# What causes tension force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

What causes a tension force? I can't understand why there is a tension force acting

Also, let's take a simple example of tension force," a block tied to a end of the rope which is hanging". When will be the tension force larger or smaller than the weight of the block ? And why? Please answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is tension force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567800/)

Answer (score 0):

At the atomic level, when atoms or molecules are pulled apart from each other and gain potential energy with a restoring force still existing, the restoring force might create what is also called tension. Each end of a string or rod under such tension could pull on the object it is attached to, in order to restore the string/rod to its relaxed length.